# Flaw in my logic of understanding the percentile() function in Hive

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql, percentile

Apologies for the rather basic question, however I have been struggling to understand and find any useful examples for a problem I have using the *percentile()* function in Hive.

Let's say I have a basic table:

```
Name  |  ID  | Salary 

Tom      25    20,000
Jim      01    25,000
Larry    72    80,000
King     05    32,000
```

and I want a percentile value for each row (calculated using the Salary column).

What I've tried to use is

```
Select
Name, 
ID, 
Salary,
percentile(Salary, array(0.25, 0.5, 0.75)) as percentile_value
group by
Name, 
ID, 
Salary
```

however the output was the exact Salary values which have led me to believe that I have misunderstood how this function works. I was expecting something along the lines of

```
0.25
0.5
0.75
0.25
```

If someone can point me in the right direction or help me further understand this it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I think its working fine. This is as per documentation -

This Returns the exact pth percentile (or percentiles p1, p2, ..) of a column in the group.

You are using `Salary` in the percentile and in the group by. Which is like you are issuing a command `percentile(constant_value, array(0.25, 0.5, 0.75))` which will always return [constant_value,constant_value,constant_value].
As far as i know percentile will be on a range of values so your group should have multiple different values. Your sample data has all unique values so i created my own data and experimented. Let me know what you think :)

My code and data below. i inserted multiple values with same id to calculate proper percentiles.

```
create table tmp2(id int, name string, sal int);
insert into tmp2 values (25, 'Larry',55000);
insert into tmp2 values (25, 'Larry',5000);
insert into tmp2 values (25, 'Larry',125000);
insert into tmp2 values (5, 'Tim',125000);
Select id, percentile(sal, array(0.25, 0.5, 0.75)) as percentile_value from tmp2 group by id ;
```

Result -

```
id  percentile_value    
5   [125000.0,125000.0,125000.0]    
25  [30000.0,55000.0,90000.0]
```

[image: Data]